# How to filter out Column data From Multiple rows data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation, jupyter-notebook

Good Evening

Hi everyone, so i got the following JSON file from Walmart regarding their product items and price.

so i loaded up jupyter notebook, imported pandas and then loaded it into a Dataframe with custom columns as shown in the pics below.

now this is what i want to do:

1. make new columns named as min price and max price and load the data into it

how can i do that ?

Here is the code in jupyter notebook for reference.

[image]

[image]

i also want the offer price as some items dont have minprice and maxprice :)

EDIT: here is the PYTHON Code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


with open("walmart.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

walmart = data["items"]


wdf = pd.DataFrame(walmart,columns=["productId","primaryOffer"])


print(wdf.loc[0,"primaryOffer"])


pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)


print(wdf)
```

Here is the JSON File:

https://pastebin.com/sLGCFCDC

Comment: could you post the code snippet instead of a screenshot? It is hard to build on a code from a screenshot. Also a sample dataset would be useful.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post, can you Please take a look. Thanks For your Time :)

Comment: I have added my solution as an answer, Feel free to have a look and accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet on top of your code would achieve the required task:

```
min_prices = []
max_prices = []
offer_prices = []
for i,row in wdf.iterrows():
    if('showMinMaxPrice' in row['primaryOffer']):
        min_prices.append(row['primaryOffer']['minPrice'])
        max_prices.append(row['primaryOffer']['maxPrice'])
        offer_prices.append('N/A')
    else:
        min_prices.append('N/A')
        max_prices.append('N/A')
        offer_prices.append(row['primaryOffer']['offerPrice'])

wdf['minPrice'] = min_prices
wdf['maxPrice'] = max_prices
wdf['offerPrice'] = offer_prices
```

Here we are checking for the 'showMinMaxPrice' element from the json in the column named 'primaryOffer'. For cases where the minPrice and maxPrice is available, the offerPrice is shown as 'N/A' and vice-versa. These are first stored in lists and later added to the dataframe as columns.

The output for `wdf.head()` would then be:

[image: Output:]

Comment: Hi thank you so much. But I would also like to share a different solution I found also. By using json_normalize